How can i add a custom icon in notification control using audio services
I want to add a lock icon instaed of play/pause in andriod and ios notification control using audio service and just_audio .when i added lock icon like this its working fine in andriod but not showing in ios .how i can show in ios .
if (isPaid)
          MediaControl.custom(
              androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_lock',
              label: 'Locked',
              name: 'Locked',
              extras: <String, dynamic>{'Locked': 1})

i have write like this but it not working in ios ,how we can show this custom icon in ios
